# Content Publishing from pulling media from Live Server rather than uploading from Local

Tags: linkedin-api

We are currently utilizing the LinkedIn API to automate content sharing on behalf of our users. Our application specifically aims to streamline the process of sharing media content, such as videos and images, on LinkedIn.
We have encountered a limitation within the current API capabilities. Our requirement is to share media content (videos/images) by pulling them directly from live servers, rather than uploading files from local storage. This is crucial for our workflow, which relies on a dynamic, server-based media repository.

Is there an existing feature in the LinkedIn API that allows for sharing media content directly from a server URL, without the need to upload from local storage?

#linkedin

we tried different API calls to fetching media from Liver servers but did not work.